# How to call function before its definition in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to use function before it definition. Because some time there will be lot of initialization variable, So I want to look my code very arrange, but if we call function after definition, my code does not looks fine, **I know it is not possible in C/C++. But If in angularjs it is possible some how, please tell.**

Please see some java-script code

```
<body>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
<br>
Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}

</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.printName();// No working
    $scope.printName=function(){
      $scope.firstName = "John";
      $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    }
    //$scope.printName();// working
});
</script>

</body>
```

Following code is working, But my requirement is as above, I defined function like `$scope.printName=function(){}` because this function is use in views as ng-click.

```
 printName();// working
    function printName(){
      $scope.firstName = "John";
      $scope.lastName = "Doe";
    }
```

Please see the demo [Pluker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9HKXqWxDGi4ueXQYNhHe?p=preview)

Answer (score 4):

The only way to do that would be to use a named function definition, which is hoisted:

```
printName();
$scope.printName = printName;

function printName() {
    $scope.firstName = ...
}
```

Is that worth it? Probably not.

If you don't need to expose the function on the scope (i.e. if `$scope.printName = printName` is unnecessary), it might be worth considering though. But in that case, are you ever going to call the function again? If not, then don't use a function at all.

Also, as an aside, "`printName`" is a misnomer for this function. If anything it's "`setDefaultName`".

Comment: I got your point, but my function definition is like `$scope.printName=function(){}`, How I will use this ..

Comment: Well, you can't. I'm showing the alternative above.